# How to create a new dataframe from input dataframe based on certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like this.

```
api                             region   base_path
https://apis.us/image/          us          /image
https://apis.emea/video/        emea        /video
https://apis.asia/docs/         asia        /docs
https://apis.emea/image/        emea        /image
https://apis.us/video/          us          /video
https://apis.us/docs/           us          /docs
https://apis.asia/location/     asia        /location
```

From the api list few apis are common in more than 1 region .Ex: `/image` is common for both `us` and `emea`. The output dataframe I want like this:

```
api_us_emea                 api_asia_us                 api_asia_emea           api_us_emea_asia        api_usa     api_emea    api_asia

https://apis.us/image/      https://apis.us/docs/       No Common api           No Common api           N/A         N/A         https://apis.asia/location/ 
https://apis.us/video/
```

Here, for common apis I always want `us` api to be present in the column value.Ex: `api_us_emea` column holds only US api, for `api_asia_emea` `asia` api and for `api_us_emea_asia` `us` api as well.
Hiow can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code snippet should give you what you want, or at least a reasonable direction to solve your problem. Basically iterate through the possible subsets of regions, and take all of the relevant base_paths for that subset. Remove those that we used already in bigger subsets that contain the subset that we are currently looking at. Hope I helped.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, combinations

data = [['https://apis.us/image/',          'us',          '/image'],
        ['https://apis.emea/video/',        'emea',        '/video'],
        ['https://apis.asia/docs/',         'asia',        '/docs'],
        ['https://apis.emea/image/',        'emea',        '/image'],
        ['https://apis.us/video/',          'us',          '/video'],
        ['https://apis.us/docs/',           'us',          '/docs'],
        ['https://apis.asia/location/',     'asia',        '/location']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['api', 'region', 'base_path'])


def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]


new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for subset in reversed(list(powerset(pd.unique(df['region'])))):
    if len(subset) > 0:
        for api_path in pd.unique(df['base_path']):
            df_path = df[df['base_path'] == api_path]
            if set(subset).issubset(set(pd.unique(df_path['region']))):
                new_dict[subset].append(api_path)
        curr_keys = list(new_dict.keys())
        for key in curr_keys:
            if set(subset).issubset(set(key)) and len(key) > len(subset):
                for remove_path in [x for x in new_dict[subset] if x in new_dict[key]]:
                    new_dict[subset].remove(remove_path)
        if subset not in new_dict:
            new_dict[subset] = []

new_df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in new_dict.items()})
new_df.columns = ['_'.join([s for s in x if not pd.isna(s)]) for x in new_df.columns]
```

`new_df` looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Great! One question, the column sequence of `new_df `-will it be same irrespective of input data?Below is `print(new_df.columns)` = `MultiIndex([('apjc', 'emea', 'asia'),
('emea','asia',nan),
('apjc','asia',nan),
('apjc','emea',nan),
('asia',nan,nan),
('emea',nan,nan),
('apjc',nan,nan),
( nan,nan,nan)])`

Comment: Well, it will contain all of the `region` combinations which include relevant data, or did I miss the point of your question?

Comment: you are right.I am just asking whether sequence of combinations remain same irrespective of input data or not?

Comment: I made a minor edit and now the column sequence will be the same for all inputs that have the same set of values in the `region` column. Also formatted the column names a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import itertools
import functools, operator

def find_coomon_elements(p):
    return list(set.intersection(*[set(li) for li in p]))

def find_unique_elements(p, l):
    merged_p = functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, p, [])
    return [x for x in l if merged_p.count(x)==1]

strings_array = df["api"].str[:-1].str.split("/").str[-2:].apply(lambda x: (x[0][5:], x[1])).values

d = dict()
[d[t[0]].append(t[1]) if t[0] in list(d.keys()) else d.update({t[0]: [t[1]]}) for t in strings_array]
se = set([x[0] for x in strings_array])


combs = [list(itertools.combinations(se, i)) for i in range(1, len(se)+1)]

col1, col2 = [], []
for item in combs[0]:
    col1.append("_".join(["api"] + list(item)))
    col2.append(["https://apis."+item[0]+"/"+s for s in find_unique_elements([d[c] for c in d.keys()], d[item[0]])])

for i in range(1, len(combs)):
    for item in combs[i]:
        common = find_coomon_elements([d[c] for c in item])
        if len(common)>0:
            col1.append("_".join(["api"] + list(item)))
            col2.append(["https://apis."+item[0]+"/"+s for s in common])
        else:
            col1.append("_".join(["api"] + list(item)))
            col2.append("No Common api")
        

output_df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":col1, "col2":col2})
output_df
```

Output:

```
               col1                                            col2
0            api_us                                              []
1          api_asia                    [https://apis.asia/location]
2          api_emea                                              []
3       api_us_asia                          [https://apis.us/docs]
4       api_us_emea  [https://apis.us/image, https://apis.us/video]
5     api_asia_emea                                   No Common api
6  api_us_asia_emea                                   No Common api
```